# Read list of objects from xml and save in shared preferences

Tags: android, json, xml, object, sharedpreferences

I have a list of objects displaying in a listview. also, I have a favorite list for saving the selected objects into shared preferences.

I've created a method when an item is marked as favorite, a backup of that `xml` file will be created in external storage.

This is how it works:

```
    private void backupFav(){
    String myPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"/backup/";
    try{
        File myFile = new File(myPath, PREFS_NAME+".xml");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(myFile);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        Map<String,?> prefsMap = settings.getAll();

        for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : prefsMap.entrySet())
        {
            pw.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());
        }
        pw.close();
        fw.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // what a terrible failure...
        Log.wtf(getClass().getName(), e.toString());
    }
}
```

It will get called when an item is marked as favorite:

```
    private void saveFavorites(List<ProductLocal> favorites) {
    String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);
    editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);
    editor.apply();
    backupFav();
}
```

Everything works so far.

(There are hundreds of items, I'm doing this for the time when user accidentally uninstalled my app, not to lose all of those data, So I do the check and restore backed-up data on every first launch).

Now my problem is in reading data from backup file.

```
    public boolean restoreFav(Context context) {
    boolean restored = false;
    File src = new File(path2+PREFS_NAME+".xml");
    ObjectInputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(src));
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEdit = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        prefEdit.clear();
        Map<String, ?> entries = (Map<String, ?>) input.readObject();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : entries.entrySet()) {
            Object v = entry.getValue();
            String key = entry.getKey();
            prefEdit.putString(key, ((String) v));
        }
        prefEdit.apply();
        restored = true;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (input != null) {
                input.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return restored;
}
```

It doesn't work. no result, no output.

Can you help,please?

**Edit**

After debugging I found that I'm getting `StreamCorruptedException`:

```
08-20 18:42:44.228: W/System.err(28802): java.io.StreamCorruptedException
08-20 18:42:44.238: W/System.err(28802):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2115)
08-20 18:42:44.238: W/System.err(28802):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:372)
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is way too broad - if you give some more details, it might be easier to help you...

Comment: @yakobom by that I mean `restoreFav` method always returns `false`. that's all I know

Comment: So start debugging the function to know more. You probably have an exception - put a breakpoint and go line by line, or look at the log...